# Python Scrapy/Selenium is skipping over most of my iterable

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a retail clothing shopping site.  For some reason, whenever I run the following code, I end up getting a couple of items from three categories (as defined in parse() as nth-children) and a slew of items from li:nth-child(5).

Sometimes the following error appears:

```
2017-01-09 20:33:30 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.example.com/jackets> (referer: http://www.example.com/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/BeardedMac/projects/thecurvyline-scraper/spiders/example.py", line 47, in parse_items
    price = node.find_element_by_css_selector('div.flex-wrapper--prod-details > div.pricing > div.price > div.standardprice').text
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 307, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 511, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed
```

However, if I change the nth-child selector to say, li:nth-child(3), I get a slew of items from that category, but I can't seem to get them all at once.

I'm pretty new to Python and Scrapy, so I might just be missing something elemental.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/MyPath/chromedriver')
    self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css('#main-menu > div > li:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+6) > a::attr(href)').extract():
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_items)

def get_item(self, response):
    sizes = response.css('#pdpMain > div.productdetailcolumn.productinfo > div > div.variationattributes > div.swatches.size > ul > li > a::text').extract()
    product_id = response.css('#riiratingsfavorites > div.riiratings > a::attr(rel)').extract_first()
    response.meta['product']['sizes'] = sizes
    response.meta['product']['product_id'] = product_id
    yield response.meta['product']


def parse_items(self, response):
    category = response.css('#shelf > div.category-header > h2::text').extract_first()
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    nodes = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#search > div.productresultarea > div.product.producttile')
    for node in nodes:
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(5)
        price = node.find_element_by_css_selector('div.flex-wrapper--prod-details > div.pricing > div.price > div.standardprice').text 
        images = node.find_element_by_css_selector('div.image > div.thumbnail > p > a > img:nth-child(1)').get_attribute('src')
        name = node.find_element_by_css_selector('div.flex-wrapper--prod-details > div.name > a').text
        product_url = node.find_element_by_css_selector('div.flex-wrapper--prod-details > div.name > a').get_attribute('href')
        product = Product ()
        product['title'] = name
        product['price'] = price
        product['product_url'] = product_url
        product['retailer'] = 'store7'
        product['categories'] = category
        product['images'] = images
        product['sizes'] = []
        product['product_id'] = []
        product['base_url'] = '' 
        product_page = response.urljoin(product_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(product_page, callback=self.get_item, meta={'product': product})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it shortly - what happens here is because scrapy is concurrent and your selenium implementation isn't, your selenium driver gets confused - during your crawl scrapy keeps asking your selenium driver to load new urls when it is still working with the old ones.

To avoid this you can disable concurrency in your spider by setting [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?#concurrent-requests) setting to `1`. E.g. add this to your `settings.py` file:

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
```

or add a `custom_settings` entry in your spider if you wish to restrict this setting to one spider:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS', 1}
```

If you want to keep concurrency (which is a really nice thing to have) you can try replacing selenium with more friendly python technologies such as [Splash](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)